# how to structure objects within an array while scraping

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm trying to structure this array to contain data for one golf hole in one object within the array. Example of what I'm trying to achieve.

Ex.

```
             let scorecard = [
                {
                    hole: 1,
                    par: 4,
                    blue: 375,
                    white: 300,
                    red: 250,
                    handicap: 1
                },
                {
                    hole: 2,
                    par: 3,
                    blue: 175,
                    white: 150,
                    red: 125,
                    handicap: 2
                },
            ]
```

The issue is how I am collecting this data. Each data collection could either have 9 holes or 18 holes and will have multiple tee colors, ex. blue, white, red on one course. Just blue and white on another.

Example of scorecard. Each card is a separate table and each row is a  with cells being  within row.
[scorecard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ln2n4.png)

Here is what I have so far but I'm not good at structuring data within these complex arrays.

```
            const res = await page.$$eval("table > tbody > tr", (holeInfo) =>
            holeInfo.map((hole) => {
                let dataStructure = []
                let dataObj = {}
                let scoreInfo = hole.querySelector("td").innerText
                let holeInfo = hole.querySelectorAll("td")

                holeInfo.forEach((x) => {
                    dataStructure.push(
                        x.innerHTML
                    )
                })

                return dataStructure;
            }),
        );
```

Output.

```
res [
[
    'Hole:', '1',   '2',
    '3',     '4',   '5',
    '6',     '7',   '8',
    '9',     'Out'
  ],
  [
    'Par:', '4',  '4',
    '4',    '4',  '4',
    '3',    '4',  '3',
    '5',    '35'
  ],
  [
    'Blue:', '372',
    '394',   '369',
    '361',   '317',
    '188',   '342',
    '184',   '570',
    '3097'
  ],
  [
    'Blue:', '372',
    '394',   '369',
    '361',   '297',
    '188',   '342',
    '184',   '570',
    '3077'
  ],
  [
    'White:', '330',
    '389',    '364',
    '291',    '285',
    '181',    '290',
    '166',    '549',
    '2845'
  ],
  [
    'White:', '0',
    '0',      '0',
    '0',      '0',
    '0',      '0',
    '0',      '0',
    '0'
  ],
  [
    'Red Intermediate:',
    '301',
    '370',
    '248',
    '275',
    '260',
    '167',
    '245',
    '99',
    '452',
    '2417'
  ],
  [
    'gold:', '0', '0',
    '0',     '0', '0',
    '0',     '0', '0',
    '0',     '0'
  ],
  [
    'Handicap:', '10',
    '4',         '5',
    '18',        '16',
    '13',        '12',
    '17',        '1',
    ''
  ],
  [
    'Hole:', '10', '11',
    '12',    '13', '14',
    '15',    '16', '17',
    '18',    'In', 'Total'
  ],
  [
    'Par:', '4',  '5',
    '4',    '4',  '4',
    '3',    '4',  '4',
    '4',    '35', '71'
  ],
  [
    'Blue:', '367',  '481',
    '352',   '313',  '323',
    '186',   '439',  '379',
    '318',   '3158', '6255'
  ],
  [
    'Blue:', '367',  '481',
    '352',   '313',  '323',
    '186',   '439',  '379',
    '318',   '3158', '6235'
  ],
  [
    'White:', '337',
    '467',    '337',
    '302',    '315',
    '14',     '429',
    '349',    '280',
    '2990',   '5835'
  ],
  [
    'White:', '0',
    '0',      '0',
    '0',      '0',
    '0',      '0',
    '0',      '0',
    '0',      '5835'
  ],
  [
    'Red Intermediate:',
    '303',
    '443',
    '311',
    '264',
    '299',
    '156',
    '278',
    '333',
    '255',
    '2642',
    '5059'
  ],
  [
    'gold:', '0', '0',
    '0',     '0', '0',
    '0',     '0', '0',
    '0',     '0', '0'
  ],
  [
    'Handicap:', '7',
    '3',         '11',
    '15',        '14',
    '6',         '2',
    '9',         '8',
    '',          ''
  ]
]
```

Comment: Based on the example image, you will sometimes have key collisions. There are two rows labeled 'blue' and two rows labeled 'white' in this example. How should those be handled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let res = [
[
    'Hole:', '1',   '2',
    '3',     '4',   '5',
    '6',     '7',   '8',
    '9',     'Out'
  ],
  [
    'Par:', '4',  '4',
    '4',    '4',  '4',
    '3',    '4',  '3',
    '5',    '35'
  ],
  [
    'Blue:', '372',
    '394',   '369',
    '361',   '317',
    '188',   '342',
    '184',   '570',
    '3097'
  ],
  [
    'Blue:', '372',
    '394',   '369',
    '361',   '297',
    '188',   '342',
    '184',   '570',
    '3077'
  ],
  [
    'White:', '330',
    '389',    '364',
    '291',    '285',
    '181',    '290',
    '166',    '549',
    '2845'
  ],
  [
    'White:', '0',
    '0',      '0',
    '0',      '0',
    '0',      '0',
    '0',      '0',
    '0'
  ],
  [
    'Red Intermediate:',
    '301',
    '370',
    '248',
    '275',
    '260',
    '167',
    '245',
    '99',
    '452',
    '2417'
  ],
  [
    'gold:', '0', '0',
    '0',     '0', '0',
    '0',     '0', '0',
    '0',     '0'
  ],
  [
    'Handicap:', '10',
    '4',         '5',
    '18',        '16',
    '13',        '12',
    '17',        '1',
    ''
  ],
  [
    'Hole:', '10', '11',
    '12',    '13', '14',
    '15',    '16', '17',
    '18',    'In', 'Total'
  ],
  [
    'Par:', '4',  '5',
    '4',    '4',  '4',
    '3',    '4',  '4',
    '4',    '35', '71'
  ],
  [
    'Blue:', '367',  '481',
    '352',   '313',  '323',
    '186',   '439',  '379',
    '318',   '3158', '6255'
  ],
  [
    'Blue:', '367',  '481',
    '352',   '313',  '323',
    '186',   '439',  '379',
    '318',   '3158', '6235'
  ],
  [
    'White:', '337',
    '467',    '337',
    '302',    '315',
    '14',     '429',
    '349',    '280',
    '2990',   '5835'
  ],
  [
    'White:', '0',
    '0',      '0',
    '0',      '0',
    '0',      '0',
    '0',      '0',
    '0',      '5835'
  ],
  [
    'Red Intermediate:',
    '303',
    '443',
    '311',
    '264',
    '299',
    '156',
    '278',
    '333',
    '255',
    '2642',
    '5059'
  ],
  [
    'gold:', '0', '0',
    '0',     '0', '0',
    '0',     '0', '0',
    '0',     '0', '0'
  ],
  [
    'Handicap:', '7',
    '3',         '11',
    '15',        '14',
    '6',         '2',
    '9',         '8',
    '',          ''
  ]
]

function getHolesAmount(arr) {
  let holesAmount = 0;
  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (parseInt(res[0][i])) {
      holesAmount += 1;
    } else {
      break;
    };
  };
  return holesAmount;
};

function fillScorecard(holesAmount, jStart, jEnd) {
  for (let i = 1; i <= holesAmount; i++) {
    let holeData = {};
    for (let j = jStart; j < jEnd; j++) {
      // remove ":" from the key and get value as integer
      holeData[res[j][0].slice(0, -1)] = parseInt(res[j][i]);
    };
    scorecard.push(holeData);
  };
};

// get first holes amount
let firstHolesAmount = getHolesAmount(res[0]);

// get second holes starting index
let secondHolesStart = 0;
for (let i = 1; i < res.length; i++) {
  if (res[i][0] === res[0][0]) {
    secondHolesStart = i;
    break;
  };
};
// get second holes amount
let secondHolesAmount = getHolesAmount(res[secondHolesStart]);

let scorecard = [];
// fill scorecard with first holes data
fillScorecard(firstHolesAmount, 0, secondHolesStart);
// fill scorecard with second holes data
fillScorecard(secondHolesAmount, secondHolesStart, res.length);

console.log(scorecard);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You absolute animal. Thank you! Now to spend a few hours understanding this code. I'm not too well versed with multidimensional arrays. Thanks again!